# charts highcharts add spacethe right side

Tags: charts, highcharts

How to add values(space) from the right side
like here
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5z3z.png)

my code here

https://jsfiddle.net/ruit/esv6t6f2/

Comment: Do you want to add a space at the right side of the chart?

Comment: Similar topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37015672/stockcharts-adding-an-offset-to-avoid-drawing-points-at-the-edge

Answer (score 0):

You can add an attribute 'spacingRight' like this in your chart array:
 // Create the chart
        chart =   $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
            chart: {
                    spacingRight: 100,