# Stockcharts - Adding an offset to avoid drawing points at the edge

Tags: javascript, highcharts

[Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) and [stockcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/products/highstock), they both provide the options to add some padding at the x axis in order to avoid drawing some values on the edge of the plot area (left or right). 
According to the doc this is archived by employing the [minPadding](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.minPadding) and [maxPadding](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.maxPadding) members of the xAxis property of the [configuration object](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock) used for constructing the chart... but in practice this is not working for stockcharts. So i wonder how i can achieve this... i leave you with the examples...

```
var examples
```

- [Working example for highcharts](http://jsfiddle.net/08jktsnr/1/)
- [Not Working example for stockcharts](http://jsfiddle.net/m7zqtz2v/)

P.D: Using property [min](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.min) for setting the lowest x value also isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maxPadding is applied when you not call the setExtremes() method. In the Highstock, we call the setExtremes to set the range on the navigator, as a result padding is ignored.

To achieve your goal, you can define the tickLength parameter and set x param per labels.

```
yAxis: {
  tickWidth: 1,
  tickLength: 50,
  labels:{
    x: 50
  }
},
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/b6a42kz0/

> OP Note: See the comments for updated answer.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian!! This helps a lot.. but i wonder how i can also achieve the same result for the points on the left edge of the x axis.

Comment: You can add extra yAxis and define offset etc. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/596mo1qc/ and http://jsfiddle.net/e1avsqoq/

Comment: Thanks @Sebastian, your workaround solves my problem!